# How to retrieve the value from sharepoint column values contains comma(,)?

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfield

In my SharePoint list I have address column with comma values.

For example Address1,Address2,Address3. When I was retrieving the value from list only I can get the address1 value.

But address column I have these 3 values Address1,Address2,Address3. How to retrieve these 3 values with comma?

```
    string AddressLine1 = Convert.ToString(dr["Address Line 1"])
string AddressLine2 = Convert.ToString(dr["Address Line 2"]);
string AddressLine3 = Convert.ToString(dr["Address Line 3"]);
string AddressLine4 = Convert.ToString(dr["Address Line 4"]);
Address = AddressLine1;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddressLine2))
 {
  Address = AddressLine1 + ',' + AddressLine2;
  }
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddressLine3))
 {
   Address = Address + ',' + AddressLine3;
 }
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddressLine4))
  {
 Address = Address + ',' + AddressLine4;
 }
    string Value = Convert.ToString(oItems["Address"]);
    if (Value != Address)
    {
        if(!htvalues.Contains("Address"))
            htvalues.Add("Address", Address);
    }
```

Value contains only address1. I want to store Address1, Address2, Address3 values in string.

[image]

When I was retrieving the values I got (155 GAITHER DRIVE) before comma value.

Below image when I was editing the value it contains all values.
[image]

Comment: What is the Data Type of the Coloumn

Comment: Multiple lines of text

Comment: I tried like this.
var AddressField = olist.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Address");
var CAddress = oItems[AddressField.Id];
var AddressasText = AddressField.GetFieldValueAsText(CAddress);

AddressasText contains only address1.

Comment: can you paste what actual value your address column is holding when do see edit item ?

Comment: Is Address your custom field? IS it plain text or Rich text?

Comment: yes Address field i was created.

Comment: May be because of the already address data contains comma(,) .. Use another character which normally not used in address..

Comment: yes IS it plain text

Comment: What is Address in condition if (Value != Address)

Comment: usually Address we can enter with comma only. That's why i used comma.

Comment: hi viraj ,i am doing adding and updating items in list.once address is added to the list, while updating i was check the condition((Value != Address) address is same value or its get changed? Value i retrieve from the sharepoint list.Address is the  datatable value

Answer (score 1):

Put .= for assigning the addressline2, addressline3 and addressline4 concatenated with ,

Right now, in your code addressline1 value is overwriting to Address in all the conditions as you have missed the .

Update the lines in if conditions of your code as below

```
Address .= Address + ',' + AddressLine2;
Address .= Address + ',' + AddressLine3;
Address .= Address + ',' + AddressLine4;
```

This will work and output all the address lines